# Setting multiple spaces in span/tspan through jquery/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Please find a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jzLu4toe/3/

```
<span id='tghj'></span>

$('#tghj').text('Hey                 There');
```

I need to set multiple spaces inside a span element. Im trying to add spaces between two text, but they get trimmed to a single space.

If possible, I need to add these spaces without adding any attributes to the span element. If thats completely impossible, other methods would be welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a non-breakable space

```
$('#tghj').html('Hey                 There'.replace(/ /g, "&nbsp;"));
```

Answer (score 1):

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_white-space.asp

you want white-space:pre; on the span.

```js
$('#tghj').text('Hey                 There');
```

```css
#tghj { white-space:pre;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<tspan id='tghj'></tspan>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways of achieving this:

1. Use a non-breakable space (like Tocino suggested) which might probably be the easiest way to do it.
2. Try adding   between the words which creates white spaces between words.
3. Edited your fiddle to achieve this (not very ideal):

HTML -

```
<div>
    <tspan id='tghj'></tspan>
    <tspan id='tghk'></tspan>
</div>
```

Javascript -

```
$('#tghj').html('Hey');

$('#tghk').html('There');
```

CSS -

```
#tghj
{
    float: left;
}
#tghk
{
    float: right;
}
```

this approach will give you some flexibility to adjust the positioning via CSS rather than Javascript.

4. Further flexibility using the exact code from point 3 except that you mend the CSS as:

   ```
   #tghk
   {
       margin-left: 30%; /**or any other value depending on the amount of space you want between the words**/
   }
   ```

There are several ways of achieving this. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `&nbsp;` as a space.